# What does "ÿþ" in the content of an URL mean?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, file-get-contents

I crawled an URL through fsockopen(), file_get_contents(), etc. and this was the very first line:

```
ÿþ#head{margin-top:5px;}
```

The response header was:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 9464
Content-Type: text/css
Last-Modified: Thu, 04 Aug 2011 13:35:23 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2015 16:43:13 GMT
```

If I open the URL through my browser this chars aren't shown. Is this something related to content compression or chunked encoding? If yes, how could I handle this without the "content-encoding" header?

Comment: It's a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). See [this related question](/questions/26493053/remove-%c3%bf%c3%be-from-string)

Comment: Thank you. I added an answer to the other question that solved my issue.